# PySpark giving incorrect result on rank for large data

Tags: python, pandas, scala, pyspark, databricks

I have data for multiple stores where the customers are unique for each store. When I select a store and use
'''

```
cust['Unique_records_group'] = cust.groupby(['STORE_ID','CUST_ID','Sub category Code'])['INVOICE_DATE'].rank(method = 'dense')
```

'''

It ranks the dates correctly, but when I use the same code for multiple stores the rank function messes up rank for invoice dates. Do we need all the stores to have the same start and end date?

The columns are the same for all the stores.

I was doing the analysis on pandas later used `pyspark.pandas` on databricks to parallelize in distributed environment to scale up on big data.

Comment: Please provide an example input dataframe and desired output dataframe. Reading text leads to misinterpretations.

Comment: why do you need ```pyspark.pandas``` to scale up? Why not work with Spark df?